# OkHttp Return cached response if server returns 5xx or is down (404)

Tags: java, okhttp

If I do a conditional request (max-age=0 and etag), it seems that to return a cached response the server must return 304 or a last-modified-since header, which won't happen if it's down or malfunctioning.

What can I do to make it return the cached response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're tracking this as [Issue 1083](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1083).

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that one.